# The usage of sigh

Tags: word-usage, expressions

Is it possible to use "let out a sigh of contentment" in my writing assignment?
My teacher told me to change it into drawing a deep breath because she consider "sigh" as a negative expression.
I am confused cause I think that it can also be used to describe a positive situation.

Comment: In my opinion your teacher is wrong about this, "sigh of contentment" is a common expression, and "drawing a deep breath" has a different connotation not associated with contentment. But still I'd change it given she'll be marking your assignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the word "sigh" be positive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290330/can-the-word-sigh-be-positive)

Comment: let out a sigh of relief is a cliché but it's possible to use contentment, sure.

Answer (score 2):

the dictionary in its examples reads:

**sigh**

Verb (used without object)

**to let out** one's breath audibly, as from sorrow, weariness, or **relief**.

Now relief is a synonym of contentment

**relief**

Synonyms for relief

alleviation
assistance
comfort
happiness
help
maintenance
reprieve
respite
satisfaction
support
abatement
amelioration
appeasement
assuagement
balm
break
breather
cheer
consolation
**contentment**
cure
deliverance
diversion
ease
easement
extrication
fix
hand
letup
lift
lightening
mitigation
mollification
palliative
refreshment
release
remission
rest
restfulness
softening
solace
succor
sustenance
allayment
comforting
load off one's mind
quick fix

dictionary.com

Furthermore drawing a deep breath holds a different meaning.

- **draw breath**

: to pause for a moment to take a breath or breathe more slowly

cambridge.org

Your teacher is clearly wrong.

Comment: Relief is a bit different from contentment. If a speeding car just misses crashing into you, you experience relief, but are a long way from contentment. And just because something is listed as a synonym that doesn't mean it has exactly the same meaning - you wouldn't seriously suggest that all those words in the list mean the same thing.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sigh says 'tiredness, sadness, **pleasure** etc.' One can certainly sigh from contentment.

Comment: I did not say that all synonyms are interchangeable. I said that semantically, they are very close.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "sigh of contentment" is common enough in published English to support a continuous Google Ngram line graph for the period 1830–2008:

[image]

The frequency of the expression is not particularly high, but it has been greater than 0% every year since 1852. For many English speakers, it is virtually a set phrase and certainly is not widely interpreted as a "negative expression," contrary to the opinion attributed to the poster's teacher.

Her are the three earliest instances I found in the course of several database searches. First, from Laughton Osborn, "[Epistle III. To Juvenal](https://books.google.com/books?id=tahcAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA223&dq=%22sigh+of+contentment%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG4IjYmbfmAhWLqZ4KHbdtCcwQ6AEwCHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22sigh%20of%20contentment%22&f=false)," in Arthur Carryl, a Novel (1841):

> Thus have I seen the new mother, whose fountains were over replenish'd, / when from the rose-tinted tube her cherub, with **sigh of contentment**, / Closing its innocent eyes, had withdrawn its soft lips in repletion, / Yield, with a smile, the rich fount, to be press'd by the soft gums of a kitten; / ...

From a translation by Hugomont of Altarouche, "[The Ounce of Snuff](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.b5220609&view=1up&seq=375)," in *The Literary Garland* (August 1843):

> My uncle never takes a pinch of snuff (and he takes a good many) without heaving a **sigh of contentment** and satisfaction, glancing at the same time at the lid of his snuff-box, which is adorned with a highly finished portrait of a fair and handsome girl.

From [*Confessions of an Homœopathist*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NpZkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA76&dq=%22sigh+of+contentment%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu0ImyoLfmAhWQ4J4KHYQEA48Q6AEwBXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22sigh%20of%20contentment%22&f=false) (1846):

> Pōble, who was impetuously struggling into his clothes, pointed to a large jug, into hich the Courier plunged, with an avidity and heartiness which soon gave him a view of the bottom, and then laid it down with a **sigh of contentment**, remarking, "Good—right good for Leipsic!"

From Caroline Gascoigne, [*Evelyn Harcourt: A Novel*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uiuo.ark:/13960/t16m3mq7h&view=1up&seq=54) (1847):

> "If you are pleased, I am indeed rewarded," replied Helen, with a **sigh of contentment**. "But now, Evelyn, dearest, let me hear you sing—let me hear if you still retain your wonderful talent. It is long since I have heard you, you know."

And from Eugène Sue, [*The Commander of Malta*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6XCaAaBGZfMC&pg=PA50&dq=%22sigh+of+contentment%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMls6YnrfmAhUWIDQIHS0_AjU4ChDoATAFegQIBBAC#v=onepage&q=%22sigh%20of%20contentment%22&f=false) (1847):

> On finding himself alone, Peyroü heaved a **sigh of contentment**, as if he at length found himself master of his little kingdom.

In short, a "sigh of contentment" is an expression of pleasure or satisfaction and is widely understood to be positive, not negative—as is the case in all five instances cited above. Although these examples are drawn from the 1840s, they use "sigh of contentment" in essentially the same way that people today use it.